# Flutter webview freezes on ios

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

I show my html data using the webview plugin on a page in my application in Flutter. It runs smoothly and without freezing on Android. But I see freezes in scroll states on iOS. What is the reason of this?
My code is as follows:

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Widget1(),
        HTMLWebView(),
        const Widget2(),
        const Widget3(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

HtmlWebView:

```
class _HTMLWebViewState extends State<HTMLWebView> {
  WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController();

  final htmlData;
  double webViewHeight = 0;
  _HTMLWebViewState({this.htmlData});

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    webViewController
      ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.transparent)
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
        onPageFinished: (url) async {
          final heightStr =
              await webViewController.runJavaScriptReturningResult(
                  "document.documentElement.scrollHeight");

          setState(() {
            webViewHeight = double.parse(heightStr.toString());
          });
        },
      ))
      ..loadHtmlString(htmlData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      height: Platform.isAndroid ? (webViewHeight / 4) : webViewHeight,
      child: WebViewWidget(controller: webViewController),
    );
  }
}
```